# How to find lost ipod touch that's offline. Bluetooth is still on and can connect to my headphones

Tags: bluetooth, ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

My 3 year old niece was playing with my ipod touch and she can't remember where she put it last. It's still in the house somewhere but i can't find it.

The wifi is off but the bluetooth is still on and connects to my wireless headphones when i turn them on.

I've tried to switch off the headphones while playing a song so it plays through the ipod speaker but it automatically pauses the song.

Is there're any way i can turn on the wifi? what are my options?

Comment: You should be able to triangulate/multilaterate the location of the iPod touch.  First, estimate the limit of the range at which your headphones work.  Then, walk around your house making careful note of locations from which you can / can not hear sounds on the headphones.  Draw a circle, on a plan of your house, with radius equal to the limit of audio range centred at each 'boundary' location.  Repeat.  The more times you repeat the more accurate your location should become.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't turn on WiFi via the Bluetooth connection.  You're headset simply doesn't have the control.  Even if paired to a computer, you can't "remote control it;"  that function simply doesn't exist.

Additionally, even if you were to use Find My to locate it, the resolution would be a few meters (about 30-40 feet).  Unfortunately, it's not "sharp" enough to tell you, "it's 10 feet from you behind the couch).

You're within range, so it's not that far.  Time to start going though the furniture with a fine tooth comb.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use voice controls to set a countdown timer, set it for thirty seconds, disconnect the headset and wait/listen.

Depending on device settings, it might cause the device to make sounds and/or vibrate. (Does the touch have vibration?)